# angularjs directive append templateUrl only on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a directive that loads a template,

```
app.directive('youtubeTrailer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      show: '=info'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_container-trailer.html',
  };
});
```

This is the ng-click action,

```
%a{"ng-click" => "toggleModal()"}
  Trailer {{$index+1}}
```

That calls this function,

```
$scope.modalShown = false;
$scope.toggleModal = function() {
  $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
};
```

And then the directive gets shown,

```
%youtube-trailer{:info => "modalShown", :show => "modalShown"}
```

This works fine, but my problem is that the template is shown in the inline code. I would like to retrieve it only when the `toggleModal()` function has been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .directive('customDirective', ['$http', '$templateCache', '$compile', function($http, $templateCache, $compile) {
    
    function getTemplate() {
       return '<div>Hello, {{ name }}!</div>';   
    };
    
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link : function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {          
        
        // instead of that you need to load and cache real template via $http
        var template = getTemplate();
        
        scope.name = 'world';
        element.replaceWith($compile(template)(scope));                    
      }
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div custom-directive></div>
</div>
```

You just need to use Angular `$http` service and load your file manually inside this event handler.

After that you need to compile it and insert to your directive element:

`element.replaceWith($compile(template)(scope));`

You also can use `{ cache: $templateCache }` setting with `$http` to cache loaded template when loaded once.

**Example:** (inside directive)

```
// you need to have injected following dependencies here: 
// $http, $compile, $templateCache

link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {
  //...
  scope.onSomeClick = function() {
      $http.get(templateUrl, { cache: $templateCache })
          .then(function(template) {
              element.replaceWith($compile(template)(scope));
          });
  };
  //...
}
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you for the suggestion but it's going a bit over my head. What do you mean with use the http service to load the file?

Comment: I'm trying to make sence of it, but it's not yet clicking. You're saying I have to do a `ng-click="onSomeClick` in my html, to call the scope function inside the directive?

Comment: @alucardu it was an example. In your case you could paste this code into your `toggleModal` function

Comment: You could also add some flag (like `scope.isLoaded`) to prevent loading template multiple times.

Comment: @alucardu added a snippet to the answer

Comment: Thanks Oleg, that makes more sence to me. But this brings me back to the original question. When I check the snippet, the template is already inside the inline code. I would like to have it so the user has to click a button to load the template in the directive.

Comment: I think this is pretty close to what I wanted. http://jsbin.com/kitifepivu/edit?html,css,js,output